# How to add Stack Canaries to Rust executables?

Tags: rust, llvm

I'm trying to harden some executables in a project I'm working on. To test, I'm using a hello world program, and checking it with [checksec](https://github.com/slimm609/checksec.sh), which reports that there are no canaries. I'm very new to Rust, and the lack of information on Google makes me feel I'm missing something obvious.

With GCC, it's a simple compiler flag: `-fstack-protector-all`. The closest thing I've found for LLVM is [safe stack](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SafeStack.html). However, that doesn't seem to be recognized by the Rust compiler when I try to pass it through to LLVM. For example:

```
rustc -C llvm-args="-fsanitize=safe-stack" -C link-arg="-fsanitize=safe-stack" test.rust
```

Results in

> rustc: Unknown command line
>   argument '-fsanitize=safe-stack'.  Try: 'rustc -help' rustc: Did you
>   mean '-spp-no-call'?

I'm using Rust 1.23.0. I'm trying to add these canaries not just on x86_64, but also on armeabi-v7a, in case that's relevant.

Comment: `test.rust` — FWIW, the extension is `.rs`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use LLVM's SafeStack right now.

`-fsanitize=safe-stack` is a *Clang* command line option, not necessarily an LLVM one. This likely explains why you get the error you do.

SafeStack support was originally brought up in [issue 26612](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26612), but enabling it was deferred until more investigation could be performed.

Since SafeStack is a sanitizer, the next thing to follow would be [issue 39699](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39699), the tracking issue for more sanitizers. Only a few sanitizers and platforms are currently supported. It might be as "simple" as adding it to a list and  creating a PR to enable it.

---

That being said, I believe Rust does have *some* amount of stack protection. For example, [this recent issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/47863) talks about how some upcoming changes to glibc are going to affect Rust's stack guard calculations.

Answer (score 7):

Currently, this isn't supported:

> We updated LLVM so there's support for this [safe stack attribute] in our LLVM, and I think that turning this on by default probably wants some investigation and likely an RFC first, so I'm going to close this for now.
>
> -- alexcrichton https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26612

I'm not able to find an RFC for this feature.

Edit: Support for stack canaries is available on nightly Rust via `-Z stack-protector` https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/84197